# How to fix a column in TStringGrid with delphi FMX?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I want to make a grid with FireMonkey where it has a fixed column, but neither `TGrid` nor `TStringGrid` have that property, nor allow me to change it dynamically at runtime, as far as I can see.

Does anyone have a way to make this work?

Imagine I have 500 columns (I don't, and I won't have that number, this is just for demonstration purposes). I want to lock the first column so its content will always be visible as the user scrolls the grid along the X axis (horizontally). Same thing as with the header row, it's always locked in place so when the user scrolls along the Y axis, the header is always visible.

I am using Delphi 10.3.3 CE.